# How can I connect to an Oracle database through a shell script?

Tags: shell, oracle-10g

I have tried to connect to an Oracle database using the below command:

```
sqlplus -s LOGIN/PASSSWD@SERVERNAME:ORA_PORT/SERVICE_NAME
```

However I couldn't connect. It was throwing the following error:

> ORA-12541: TNS: no listener.

How can I fix this?

Comment: check if your listener is up and running

Comment: Yes its up only..i can able to connect through sqlplus but couldn't able to do it through shell script..

Comment: and how are you connection to SQLPlus? What's the exact command?

Comment: conn username/password is command i used to connect through SQLPlus..Also system throws  
ORA-12162 TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified error after ORA-12541: TNS: no listener..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're entering the wrong TNS Name while connecting. Check the TNSNames defined in `$oracle_home\network\admin\tnsnames.ora` and use the defined TNS Name as

```
sqlplus -s LOGIN/PASSSWD@tnsname
```